# Opening ICS file using UIDocumentInteractionController on iOS > 5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, calendar

I am targeting iPhone and iPads running iOS ≥ 5 and [iOS 4.2 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-4_2/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010243-CH1-SW11) imply that the following code should work:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
interactionController.delegate = self;
BOOL worked = [interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:buttonFrame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

However it doesn't work on iOS ≥ 6. Is this a documented regression?

I have tried opening the same ICS file I have been using in my app via the Mail app or via Safari and the file opens as expected in the Calendar app with the option to add it.

How can I reproduce the behaviour of iOS < 6 or of Mail and Safari (all versions of iOS)?